# Multiple column chart using lastrow - 1

Tags: excel, vba

My current sub uses the `lastrow` which includes the total in my data set, I want to use one above the `lastrow` so the chart doesn't include the "Total Row" but getting errors.

Ive tried to do `range("A6",Range(LastRow)`

Ive also tried `Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown)-1 )`

```
Sub NewChart()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Select
    Union( _
    Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown)), _
    Range("E6", Range("E6").End(xlDown))).Select
    Charts.Add 
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A6:E" & LastRow)`. And try to [avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: The range ("A6:E" & LastRow) will use data in columns B,C,D though. I only want columns A,D

Comment: Then `Union(Range("A6:A" & LastRow), Range("E6:E" & LastRow))`.